# Samsung Galaxy 3 Questions

Tags: samsung-galaxy-apollo, front-camera

I plan to buy a Samsung Galaxy 3. Here are my questions:

1. Does the Galaxy 3 have a front-facing camera?
2. How is the main camera (in terms of clarity)?
3. Can the browser support multiple windows?

Answer (score 4):

1. No - one 3.15MP camera on the rear 3.15 MP, 2048x1536 pixels, autofocus, Geo-tagging, face and smile detection, Video- QVGA@15fps.
2. [Here's a comparison](http://www.gsmarena.com/piccmp.php3?idType=1&idPhone1=3395&idPhone2=3516&idPhone3=3403) of the Galaxy 3 alongside images from its peers.
3. Yes, the default browser does indeed support multiple windows.

Answer (score -1):

Now that the phone is released, I believe Sparx's answer is incorrect for part 1.

It has an 8 MP rear camera, and a 1.9 MP front facing camera.